# Socket.io mysql connection error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When i started my socket on the npm , my Mysql conection going to down about 30 sec .I do not know why. The mysql insert method worked . But when i am waiting about 1 min -30 sec the conenction shut down.

**This is error code ;**

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
>       at Protocol.end (C:\xampp\htdocs\tem\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:109:13)
>       at Socket. (C:\xampp\htdocs\tem\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:115:28)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)

**This is my source code;**

```
var app = require('express')();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "hostname",
    user: "username",
    password: "pw",
    database: "db"
});
con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('UnSuccesfull');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Succesfull');
});
app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.sendfile(__dirname+"/asd.html");

});
io.on('connection',function(socket){

    var UserLog={
        Log:'A User Connected'
    };
    con.query('Insert Into Log SET ?',UserLog ,function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
    });
});
var port=xx;
http.listen(port,'xx.xx.xx');
```

Comment: try sequelize http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you, use connection pooling.

You can create connection pool like that;

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : 60,
host    : hostname,
user    : dbUser,
password: dbPass,
database: dbName,
multipleStatements: true
});
```

And when you need to run query on mysql;

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.query( "SELECT * FROM `users`", function(err, users) {
                connection.release();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hocam 4 saniyede bir mysql boş sorgu yapsam SELECT X FROM Y diye sıkıntı cıkar mı ? aynı mantık olsa gerek

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz sıkıntı çıkartacağını sanmıyorum, ayrıca limit 1 diyerek biraz daha az yük bindirmiş olursun.

Comment: Tamamdır hocam o şekilde yapayım :) eyvallah

Answer (score 0):

io.on('connect')*

The database rules is correct ?

Comment: if(err) throw err;